# Android How to Make Search in Google Map Without using google place API

Tags: android, api, google-maps, google-api

I have use Place API for **search nearest place** using keyword provide by Google like(restaurant,ATM),but I want to search "HeadShop" which are not available in **Google place API** keywork .

My question is how could  I search "headshop" without using place API.

if someone identofy this issue please help me thanks

Comment: If some third party provides it's API, you can use them, or create your own, or make it fully user input.

Answer (score 0):

Code your own geocoder using google geocoding API.

you can start [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

Use `Asynctask` !! pass your location name and get `LatLng` values from geocoder and plot them in your `Maps`

Here's my code

```
private class GeocoderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, LatLng> {

        @Override
        protected LatLng doInBackground(String... locationName) {
            // Creating an instance of Geocoder class
            Log.d(tag, "background");
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.ENGLISH);
            List<Address> addresses = null;
            String loc = locationName[0];
            LatLng position = null;

            try {
                // Getting a maximum of 3 Address that matches the input text
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationName[0], 3);
                Log.d("bump", "background try ");
                if (addresses != null && !addresses.isEmpty()) {
                    Address first_address = addresses.get(0);
                     position = new LatLng(first_address.getLatitude(),
                     first_address.getLongitude());
                      return position;

                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (position == null) {
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(
                        "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="
                                + loc + "&sensor=true");

                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response;
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                try {
                    response = client.execute(httpGet);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
                    int b;
                    while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
                        stringBuilder.append((char) b);
                    }
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    // Log.d("MAPSAPI", stringBuilder.toString());

                    jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
                    if (jsonObject.getString("status").equals("OK")) {
                        jsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results")
                                .getJSONObject(0);
                        jsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("geometry");
                        jsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("location");
                        String lat = jsonObject.getString("lat");
                        String lng = jsonObject.getString("lng");

                        // Log.d("MAPSAPI", "latlng " + lat + ", "
                        // + lng);

                        position = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(lat),
                                Double.valueOf(lng));
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(tag, e.getMessage(), e);
                }
            }
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(LatLng result) {
            Log.d("bump", "post");

            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
              markerOptions.position(result); //


            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(result));
         }

    }
```

Comment: thanks Rhth , this code is usefull for search location ,but i want to search nearest headshop by include  current lat and long . can i put current lat & long in above url?

Comment: yes..as it gives 3 results check for the nearest distance of the LatLng's from current location then mark only that point

Comment: Rhth I put current loc and Long in url but its find current address ,I want to "search" not looking for the current Address ,want to search headshop using current location.

Comment: So you always want to search for headshop only ?? Then hardcore locationname to 'headshop'.What do you mean by 'search using current location ?